# How to get rid of SqlException Timeout expired in WCF Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on asp.net web application, this application interacts with sql server Database through WCF Service. I get the following Exception sometimes but not every time.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  
The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.  
This failure occured while attempting to connect to the Principle server.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): 
The wait operation timed out
```

I know there are multiple reasons for this. There's a deadlock somewhere or The query is too complex.

At some place I have read that setting `CommandTimeout` of `SqlCommand` object can solve this issue.

So before applying this logic I want to know the strong reason of this issue and If there is any other workaround to be done to get rid of this issue please let me know. If I'm missing anything please let me know.

Comment: Did you try examining your SQL query and see if it can be optimized?
This should be the correct approach before increasing timeout value.

Comment: one more option will be wrapping the query in try catch in sql procedure.. so if any exception occurs you can fail it instead of blocking..

Comment: It would seem that this has nothing to do with WCF.

Comment: You could use the query analyzer that is built into SQL Management Studio to find out, which part(s) of your query is contributing the most in terms of processing time. For example, table scans can be hugely expensive on large tables; index seeks and key lookups is what you usually want to see. In such cases, adding indexes *might* help (they usually will speed up reading but slow down inserting and updating).

Comment: do you use linq ? if so than use query analyzer so you will get better idea.also increase value of CommandTimeout